# how to sort the values comma delimited using PySpark?

Tags: pyspark

I have the following dataframe.
The `values` column contains multiple time string values and I want to sort these values as ascending manner as shown in a after part below.

Before

```
id    values
1    2023-04-02, 2023-02-01, 2023-01-04
2    2023-02-01, 2023-01-04, 2023-02-07
3    2023-01-08, 2023-01-05, 2023-01-02
```

After

```
id    values
1    2023-01-04, 2023-02-01, 2023-04-02
2    2023-01-04, 2023-02-01, 2023-02-07
3    2023-01-02, 2023-01-05, 2023-01-08
```

I am using the pyspark and how to achieve it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DataFrame (df_1):

```
+---+----------------------------------+
|id |value                             |
+---+----------------------------------+
|1  |2023-04-02, 2023-02-01, 2023-01-04|
|2  |2023-02-01, 2023-01-04, 2023-02-07|
|3  |2023-01-08, 2023-01-05, 2023-01-02|
+---+----------------------------------+
```

Import necessary functions

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import split, array_sort, concat_ws
```

1. Use `split()` to separate string column value based on delimiter

```
df_2 = df_1.withColumn("value", split("value", ", "))
```

2. Use `array_sort()` to sort your element

```
df_3 = df_2.withColumn("value", array_sort("value"))
```

3. Use `concat_ws()` to join array element into string type with a value delimitor

```
df_4 = df_3.withColumn("value", concat_ws(", ", "value"))

df_4.show(truncate=False)
```

***Output:***

```
+---+----------------------------------+
|id |value                             |
+---+----------------------------------+
|1  |2023-01-04, 2023-02-01, 2023-04-02|
|2  |2023-01-04, 2023-02-01, 2023-02-07|
|3  |2023-01-02, 2023-01-05, 2023-01-08|
+---+----------------------------------+
```